# how to compute marginal effects of predictors in NBSTRAT (truncated & endogenously stratified negative binomial) model? (Stata)

Tags: stata, negative-binomial-distribution, endogeneity, marginal-effect, truncated-distributions

I'm using STATA 16.0 to develop recreational demand function via using NBSTRAT model. I have several factor and continuous variables that force me to use "xi:" prefix in the model syntax because "nbstrat" is user-written command which is not allowed to use factor variables without this prefix.
Here is the code that I use:

```
xi: nbstrat S8_y i.Ad S6_RC_En S13_dogal S13_engelli S13_profil S15_RC_Tek i.S31_RCTip S33_RC_Yesil i.S38_Arac S7_yil S14_Ortak S14_Alis S14_Engel S14_Guvenlik S16_Mal S23_puan S34_uzak S36_Gelir, vce(robust)
```

I obtain acceptable beta coefficients as output, however, I also want to compute marginal effects of each predictor that's why I use the code below:

```
margins, dydx(*) vce(unconditional)
```

But unfortunately, I have an error as:

```
. margins, dydx(*) vce(unconditional)
cannot compute vce(unconditional);
predict after ml could not compute scores
r(322);
```

Why does the model give this error? and How can I fix it? or what can be the alternative ways to get marginal effects without changing the model syntax?

I will appreciate it if anyone helps me with that issue.
Kind regards
Nuket Ipek Cetin

Comment: Why do you have vce(unconditional)?

Comment: Because I'm using vce(robust) in the model syntax which is required from nbstrat model based on using on-site survey data. And in the Stata guideline it is stated that: 

"If have a representative random sample, when you fit the model, you need to specify the vce(robust) or vce(cluster clustvar) option. When you issue the margins command, you need to specify the vce(unconditional) option."

That's why I use vce(unconditional)...

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I will appreciate if you can share your ideas regarding the possible reasons for indicated problem...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an area that I am very familiar with and this is getting into off-topic territory. It's also cross-posted at [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1603643-how-to-compute-marginal-effects-in-nbstrat-truncated-endogenously-stratified-negative-binomial-model-stata). I would try adding the force option to margins and trying to come up with a simple reproducible example that shows the problem. For example, does it work without xi? Does it work without vce(unconditional)?

Comment: Thanks, @DimitriyV.Masterov for your response. I have two answers for you:
a)  command can work without vce(unconditional) however the values of dx/dy are completely same with beta coefficients of the model. At that point, I'm not sure this is correct or not because I could not find any exact info especially about nbstrat model structure

Comment: b) unfortunately the nbstrat model does not work without "xi:" as you can see the syntax and error message below: 
`nbstrat S8_y i.Ad S6_RC_En S13_dogal S13_engelli S13_profil S15_RC_Tek i.S31_RCTip S33_RC_Yesil i.S38_Arac S7_yil S14_Ortak S14_Alis S14_Engel S14_Guvenlik S16_Mal S23_puan S34_uzak S36_Gelir, vce(robust)
factor-variable and time-series operators not allowed
r(101)`

Comment: I would e-mail the authors. This is pretty obscure stuff.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to do that but unfortunately, I did not get any response from them. nbstrat is quite some old command which was developed in 2005, do you think this can be the reason of problems (due to lack of updates etc.) @DimitriyV.Masterov